# ItextSharp and checkboxes

Tags: c#, pdf, checkbox, itext

Hi to everyone I'm facing the following issue, I have a pdf file with a form that must be filled by a program, I've written a program in C#, using `itextsharp` to fill all required fields, all seems to work fine and the final pdf, opening it on the screen is ok, but when I print the pdf the signed symbol in checkbox field is replaced with a black circle......

I've attached an image to clarify the issue, there is the correct signed `checkbox` displayed on screen, the wrong circle symbol displayed printing the file or clicking on it and a list of the possible options

[image]

Can someone suggest me a way to identify and solve this issue.

Here are the files
[before Editing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjueirhghp7ytf7/beforeEditing.pdf?dl=0)

[afterEditing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wysc4rxlpspx2lk/afterEditing.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share a document in question? What reader/printer application are you using?

Comment: Hi Setasign, I've created a small document just to reproduce the issue, document beforeEditing.pdf is the fresh document, document afterEditing.pdf is the document filled with ITextSharp.....if you try to print the document you can see that the aspect of radiobutton is changed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What reader/printer application are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Canon iR-ADV C5030/5035

Comment: and acrobat reader 2015 as application

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems concerning checkBoxes and iTextSharp, my workaround for that was to avoid using chekcBoxes, instead, i draw a square, put a text area in it and fill it with "X" or not depending on business condtitons.

I based my answer on your mention

> I have a pdf file with a form that must be filled by a program

if you have to fill the pdf manually this workaround will no more be valid.

Hope This Helps

Comment: Thank you for your help Karoui, unfortunately I can't follow your suggestion, I need if possible to print the correct symbol.